# How to get a previous variable in an if-else statement code block?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some events logged in an if/else statement, for example:

```
function foo(shown) {
  if (shown == "div1") {
    function check() {
      var var_2 = new Date().toISOString();
      console.log("time", window.var_1 + " - " + var_2);
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("button2");
    button.addEventListener("click", check);
  } else if (shown == "div2") {
    var var_3 = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log("time:", var_2 + " - " + var_3);
  }

  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", check);
  return true;
}
```

The problem is that here:

```
    } else if (shown == 'div2') {

      var var_3 = new Date().toISOString();
      console.log('time:', var_2 + ' - ' + var_3 );

    }
```

`var_2`is not reachable, I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: var_2 is not defined`, how can I access to this variable and log it into the console?

Comment: Don't declare functions in `if` clauses; it's an error in "strict" mode and generally a bad practice. And you cannot access a variable declared in a nested function. You could return the value from the function and set a variable in the outer scope.

Comment: I see, I am pretty new with javascript, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Pointy - It's not an error in strict mode. Strict mode just makes it slightly more rational when you do it (slightly). But yes, absolutely a bad idea in the general case.

Comment: I got the feeling it was a bad preactice, however I am recording some clicked events. Is there any way of getting those variables under this conditions?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder really? huh, I thought that `function` declarations in conditional blocks was disallowed. It probably should be, since it's weird.

Comment: Another thing that's highly questionable is adding an event listener in a function like that. Every time the function is called (and note that we don't know how or why it's called), another event listener will be added.

Comment: or is there any way of storing all the logged events in an array and then print them? Maybe like that is better?

Comment: @Pointy - Nope, ES5 still left them as an allowable extension, even in strict mode. :-) I think there was hope of evolving them into function statements (though they could have disallowed them in ES5 when strict mode was introduced and then relaxed that later -- but there was a lot going on and lots of conflicting inputs and getting ES5 out was herculean enough). So ES2015 codified their semantics in both loose and strict mode based on the intersection of what worked cross-browser and left it there. I had great fun trying to explain *that* in Chapter 3! ;-)

Comment: lol I'll check it out, I kind-of started in the middle of the book

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variables at the beginning of your function:

```js
function foo(shown) {
  let var_2 = "";
  let var_3 = "";
  if (shown == "div1") {
    function check() {
      var_2 = new Date().toISOString();
      console.log("time", window.var_1 + " - " + var_2);
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("button2");
    button.addEventListener("click", check);
  } else if (shown == "div2") {
    var_3 = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log("time:", var_2 + " - " + var_3);
  }

  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", check);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I declared `var_2` with at the top and I am getting `undefined`

Comment: The output looks something like this: `time:  - 2021-02-28T11:39:47.896Z`